# Препарат, который или которого?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Который или которого?

На складе имеется новый препарат, который ещё не видели в аптеках. (или которого?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. Стилистически предпочтительнее винительный падеж (который).